# MySQL/Percona Audit Log Plugin Not Working

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, percona, audit

I've been looking to implemement the `Percona Audit Log plugin`. So far I have installed it and configured it, and it seems to be working ok.

*Except*, I have installed it on a slave Database as I don't want to run it on my master database (because of the additional overhead, and the fact it requires a DB restart if I want to configure it), and it doesn't appear to be logging any queries.

I have set up a script to import the logfile back into a standalone MySQL instance so I can query it, and from what I can tell it only records events that happen locally on the slave, but ignores all queries that are replicated from the master.

I implemented it because I need a way to audit the types of statements being run on our databases (`ALTER`, `UPDATE` etc.) but if they're not going to be recorded it's not much use.

I can't see anything in the documentation for this (either Percona or MySQL). Does anyone else use this, and is it just me that has missed something or am I going to have to go back to the drawing board.

I'm running MySQL 5.5 with Statement Based Replication.